# Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.StackOverflowException' en System.Windows.Forms.dll C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Com indica el titulo tengo este error que me marca al momento de dar clic a través del botón cerrar (x) y cuando doy clic en cancelar dentro del formulario.

Este es el codigo en metodo  form_closing

```
private void Frm_Registrar_Paciente_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
            Frm_Escoger_Profesional frm = new Frm_Escoger_Profesional();
            frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            frm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (StackOverflowException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Y este mismo código lo uso en el botón salir

```
private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
            Frm_Escoger_Profesional frm = new Frm_Escoger_Profesional();
            frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            frm.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (System.StackOverflowException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Que podría estar realizando de manera errónea? que causa esta excepción?

De antemano agradezco sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento FormClosing se ejecuta justo antes de que se cierre el form por ello el llamar a this.Close() lo desencadena. Por esa razón, estás creando un bucle infinito ya que cuando entra al evento FormClosing, y llamas al método Close() con la sentencia this.Close() entonces vuelves a entrar al evento FormClosing y así sucesivamente, lo que provoca la excepción.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
private void Frm_Registrar_Paciente_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;
        Frm_Escoger_Profesional frm = new Frm_Escoger_Profesional();
        frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        frm.Show();
        // this.Close(); Prueba quitando esta línea
    }
    catch (StackOverflowException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: efectivamente como indicas el solo quitar esa pequeña linea logro ejecutar el código sin problema.